# Req.session.users not available in other routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, sequelize.js

i guys I am currently using nodejs with express session and connect session sequelize.

Currently I am trying to pass my userID from session and to be accessed at another add product page. So that the database can identify based on userID. I am getting req.session.users is not a function.

Below is my code.

Sessions login page:

```
const User = require('../models/user')

exports.postLoginPage = (req,res,next) =>{

User.findByPk(1)
        .then(users =>{
req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
req.session.users = users;
res.redirect('/');
        })
        .catch(err =>{
console.log(err)
        })

}
```

the addProduct Page

```
exports.postaddProductsMale = (req,res,next) =>{
const title = req.body.title;
const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
const price = req.body.price;
console.log(+req.session.users)
req.session.users.createProduct({
title:title,
imageUrl:imageUrl,
price:price
  })
    .then(results =>{
console.log('Product created')
res.redirect('male_section');
    })
    .catch(err =>{
console.log(err)
    })
};
```

this is my error :

```
TypeError: req.session.users.createProduct is not a function
   at exports.postaddProductsMale (C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\Hobby\projects\javascript\ecommerce clothing\maarancode\controllers\admin.js:28:23
```

I can get the data to the other routes using req.user not sure why req.session.users is not working.

Appreciate your feedback on this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`req.session` must be serializable so that it can be stored between requests, see for example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session). But a function like `req.session.users.createProduct` is not serializable, so it may not survive until the next request.

See the following example

```js
express()
.use(session({
  secret: "Se$$ion",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
.use("/test", function(req, res) {
  if (!req.session.mybool) {
    req.session.mybool = true;
    req.session.myfunc = function() {};
  }
  res.end(typeof(req.session.mybool) + " " + typeof(req.session.myfunc));
})
.listen(80);
```

If you make two requests, the first response is `boolean function` but the second is `boolean undefined`.

Comment: I dont not think that is the issue here. I am able to access `req.session.isLoggedIn = true;` in other routes. My concern is that does using `express session` and `connect-session-sequelize` affect how associations work in `sequelize`

Comment: The boolean `req.session.isLoggedIn` is serializable whereas the function `req.session.users.createProduct` is not. See the code in my answer.

Comment: ok I managed to break down what is the issue when using  `req.session.isLoggedIn` I am getting the following `{
  id: 1,
  name: 'test',
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  createdAt: '2021-10-21T16:33:04.000Z',
  updatedAt: '2021-10-21T16:33:04.000Z'
}`  but with `req.users` I am getting this  `{
  dataValues: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Maaran',
    email: 'maaran@gmail.com',
    createdAt: 2021-10-21T16:33:04.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-10-21T16:33:04.000Z
  }` I am missing the key:values pair when using req.session. I am almost there. Will update the outcome.